# HIS Radeon HD 5770 (H577FK1GD) isn't recognized on an H-JOSHUA-H61-uATX motherboard

Tags: graphics-card, amd-radeon, hp-pavilion, post, hp

I've got an old HP H-JOSHUA-H61-uATX motherboard that is running just fine after a BIOS update to 8.20. But when I plug in my working H577FK1GD video card there's no POST. pcpartpicker says they are compatible (they don't have the joshua mb, so I chose the Asus H61M-C which has the same chipset).

Comment: The motherboards' common chipset is not as relevant as think, if at all. Check required PCIe version for the graphics and other details. Another detail to keep in mind - and that should definitely have been mentioned in the question - is the old board is an HP part. So, it may and likely has HP firmware with whitelist or something similar.

Comment: The article quoted in the answer definitely suggests HP "whitelisted" hardware. You may try again after disabling Secure Boot but it may be a waste a time. The point being, trying to reuse old hardware is commendable but parts from mainstream PC manufacturers is more often than not a bad idea due to artificial limitations.

Comment: @ChanganAuto From my reading the video card is PCIE 2.1 and the board is PCIE 2.0. So it should work. I am against a wall here trying to make this system work as I'm donating it and the target users (teen brothers) don't have the money for a new build.

Comment: Right. Hva e you tried the suggestion in the answer, disabling Secure Boot?

Comment: @ChanganAuto yes. no bueno.

Comment: If so I'm afraid there's nothing else to try other than obtaining a compatible non-HP firmware without the whitelist.

Comment: How do I tell which one is compatible?

Comment: Almost impossible to find it.

Answer (score 0):

##### Check secure boot

> [**HP Desktop PCs:** Computer Does not Start After Installing a Video Card](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03653200)
> *HP computers that come with Windows 10 and Windows 8 installed use an AMI BIOS version 8 that is compatible with UEFI (Unified Extensible Firmware Interface). This version of the BIOS includes and automatically enables Secure Boot, **which can prevent your computer from starting after you install a video card other than the card that shipped with the computer.***

> If the card is not recognized, Windows does not use the card when it boots up, and you may experience problems starting the computer, or there might be no video output at all.
>
> To resolve the issue, you can use a video card that Secure Boot recognizes, or you can disable Secure Boot and enable Legacy Boot in the BIOS. This document explains how to disable Secure Boot and enable Legacy Boot.

##### 1. Remove Radeon HD 5770

Temporarily remove the add-on card that is preventing boot.

##### 2. Disable Secure Boot & enable Legacy Boot

1. Turn on computer and press <kbd>F10</kbd> repeatedly, about once every second, until the **Computer Setup** opens; ***or***
   Turn on the computer and press <kbd>Escape</kbd> repeatedly, about once every second, until the **Startup menu** opens. Then press <kbd>F10</kbd> to open **Computer Setup**.
   [image]
2. Use right arrow <kbd>►</kbd> to choose **Security menu**, then down arrow <kbd>▼</kbd> to select **Secure Boot Configuration**, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
   [image]
3. Accept the warning by clicking <kbd>F10</kbd>
   [image]
    
   [image]
4. Use the down arrow <kbd>▼</kbd> to select **Secure Boot**, then use the right arrow <kbd>►</kbd> to modify the setting to **Disable**.
5. Use the down arrow <kbd>▼</kbd> to select **Legacy Support**, then use the right arrow <kbd>►</kbd> to modify the setting to **Enable**.
6. Press <kbd>F10</kbd> to accept the changes.
7. Left arrow <kbd>◄</kbd> to select **File** menu, then down arrow <kbd>▼</kbd> to select **Save Changes and Exit**, then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select **Yes**.
8. The computer restarts and displays a message indicating the boot mode has changed.
   [image]
9. Type the **four-digit code** shown in the message, then <kbd>Enter</kbd> **<sup>*</sup>**

**<sup>*</sup>** *No text field displays for the code. This is expected behavior. When you type the numbers, the code is logged even without a text field.*

##### 3. Install the new video card

Install the desired video card in the computer. Make sure the card is compatible with the computer and meets the specifications for your PC.

Comment: Nice answer but this isn't the problem. Graphics not being properly recognized can indeed be Secure Boot related but in that case the issues is with DRIVERS and drivers alone (SB prevents loading unsigned drivers), it'll boot to the OS the same way albeit with lower resolution because it'll be using a generic VESA video mode. If/when **there's no POST** then **the problem has nothing to do with what is being discussed in this answer**- It is in all likelihood an actual compatibility issue (the board is an original HP part so...)

Comment: @ChaganAuto your assertion contradicts the support article from HP.  That being said an actual compatibility issue is of course a possible reason.

Comment: No, my assertion complements rather than contradicts that 10 years old HP article. And I can go further and correct the dumb thing they say about enabling Legacy mode. We're almost in 2023 so no, definitely not. And if I wanted to nitpick I would also mention that their statement "use a video card that Secure Boot recognizes" is stupid AF. Secure Boot is all about policing bootloaders and drivers, it has absolutely nothing to do with hardware detection and initialization. Is it really an official HP post or some well-intentioned user at their forum?

Comment: Swearing isn't helpful.  The article https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03653200 appears to be provided by HP and not a *helpful* user.  The age of the article is in line with the age of the chipset in question. You may however be right about the underlying issue, and may be right that HP posted a support article that is incorrect at many turns and has not ever corrected that error.   Given this forum, and your own experience here, I would expect you to support your assertions with references, and conduct yourself appropriately.

Comment: The part you didn't quote is very interesting. This pearl says it all (for those that can read between the lines): *When your computer was manufactured, [the HP **modified**] UEFI created a list of keys that identify **trusted hardware*** This is a "whitelist", no more no less in a not very honest or upfront manner. They tried to disguise what is their corporate decision behind technical jargon about the "new" thing (UEFI) making it look like a "feature" when it really is another subtle way to lockdown customers.

Comment: Followed the steps to disable Secure Boot and enable Legacy Support. There's no video signal still, but judging by the HDD light activity the system does POST and boot.